# How to use RabbitMq Direct reply-to queue extension

Tags: c++, rabbitmq

I created one Client and a Server. How can I use  RabbitMq Direct reply-to queue extension?

**client code**

```
AMQPExchange * ex = amqp.createExchange("");
AMQPQueue * ReplyToQueue = amqp.createQueue("amq.rabbitmq.reply-to");  
ReplyToQueue->Consume(AMQP_NOACK);
```

In the above code, *Consume* gives the following exception

```
server error 404, message 'NOT_FOUND - no queue 'amq.rabbitmq.reply-to' in vhost '/'' class=60 method=20
```

I follow [Direct reply-to rabbitmq](https://www.rabbitmq.com/direct-reply-to.html)

Comment: Which `ccp` are you using?

Comment: @Gabriele   what is stands for ccp?

Comment: Sorry, I mean C++ / C!

Comment: I have use c++11 and my gcc version is 4.8.4

Comment: What version of RabbitMQ are you using? This feature is present since 3.4.0 http://www.rabbitmq.com/release-notes/README-3.4.0.txt

Comment: I updated my rabbitmq broker to 3.5.5 now it is working fine.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'd say you are missing  to call

```
ReplyToQueue.Declare()
```

That  [declare](https://github.com/akalend/amqpcpp/blob/ddfdfdf1f2f2d0286ba1090d37fda960e3148c2e/src/AMQPQueue.cpp#L52) a queue

**Edit**

I add the `oldsound` comments, since my answer it is not property correct:

> You can't name queues with the amq. prefix, but the reply to is an
>   exception to the rule, see: rabbitmq.com/direct-reply-to.html and https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/blob/master/src/rabbit_channel.erl#L1264
>
> "There is no need to declare this "queue" first, although the client
>   can do so if it wants." That's form the reply-to queue docs –

Comment: It show exception for Access refused as my queue name start from amq.

Comment: @ChintanPatel yes, you can't call queues with prefix `amq.`

Comment: You can't name queues with the `amq.` prefix, but the reply to is an exception to the rule, see: https://www.rabbitmq.com/direct-reply-to.html and https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/blob/master/src/rabbit_channel.erl#L1264

Comment: "There is no need to declare this "queue" first, although the client can do so if it wants."

That's form the reply-to queue docs

Answer (score 0):

As per the comments, the error message `NOT_FOUND - no queue 'amq.rabbitmq.reply-to' in vhost '/'` most likely means that the RabbitMQ instance you're connecting to is too old to support [the "direct reply-to" extension](https://www.rabbitmq.com/direct-reply-to.html).  It was introduced in RabbitMQ 3.4.0; see [the release notes](https://www.rabbitmq.com/release-notes/README-3.4.0.txt).